# How to know if a row doesn't exist?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following query:

```
SELECT rowid FROM table1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

And as well I have another table (table3). In that table I have columns table1_id and table2_id. table1_id is a link to a row in table1 and table2_id is a link to a row in another table.

I want in my query to get only those results that are defined in table3. Only those that have table1 rowid in their table1_id column. There may not be any columns at all referring to a certain table1 rowid so in this case I don't want to receive them.

How can I achieve this goal?

Update: I tried the following query, which doesn't work:

```
SELECT rowid FROM table1
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT table1_id FROM table3 WHERE table1_id = table1.rowid)
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT rowid FROM table1
WHERE rowid IN ( SELECT DISTINCT table1_id FROM table3 )
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

This query means "choose at random a row from `table1` which has an entry in `table3`".

Every row in table1 equal likelihood of being selected (`DISTINCT`) as long as it is referenced at least once in `table3`.

If you are trying to get more than one result, then you should remove the "`ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1`" clause.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to select more than *just* a rowid, you need to **SELECT from a [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))** between the tables you're interested in. SQLite doesn't have the full set of standard JOIN functionality, so you'll need to re-work your query so it can use a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join).

```
SELECT table1.rowid, table1.other_field
FROM table3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON table3.table1_id = table1.rowid
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1;
```